# AS3 XML to multidimensional array

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

I've looked everywhere, and although there are many explanations, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here is my xml structure:

```
 <question> 
            <q1> Who coined the term “Clinical Psychology”? </q1>       
            <answer> Lightner Witmer </answer>

            <option1> Stanley Hall </option1>
            <option2> Lightner Witmer </option2>
            <option3> Henry P. David </option3>
    </question>
```

I can loop through fine and pick out the questions and answers, then throw them into separate arrays. The problem I'm having is looping and pulling the options into a multidimensional array like such:

```
var one:Array = new Array( 3 ); 
one[0] = ["Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David"];
one[1] = ["Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David"];
one[2] = ["Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David"];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var answers:Array = [];

    for(var i = 0; i< xml.question.length; i++){
    var node:Array = [];
    node.push(xml.question[i].option1);
    node.push(xml.question[i].option2);
    node.push(xml.question[i].option3);

//or
    var node:Array = [xml.question[i].option1,xml.question[i].option2,xml.question[i].option3];

    answers.push(node);

    }
```

answers for questions can now be retrieved:

```
answers[questionIndex][answerIndex];
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are setting up the array in the form you want but, going off the code you posted.
Have you tried?

```
var one:Array = new Array( 3 ); 
one[0] = new Array( "Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David" );
one[1] = new Array( "Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David" );
one[2] = new Array( "Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David" );
```

With something like this I would prefer to have a questions array with objects as the elements. Each object would hold all the info about that question. This would allow for a custom class to be assigned for each question. Or a basic dynamic object could be used

```
var questions:Array = new Array();

var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.question = "Who coined the term 'Clinical Psychology'?"
obj.correctAnswer = "Lightner Witmer";
obj.possibleAnswers =new Array( "Stanley Hall", "Lightner Witmer", "Henry P. David" );

questions.push( obj );
```

Comment: This way does seem to make more sense. If I have time tonight, I'll try it out. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, its a little more coding but a lot more easier to read. unlike my writing skills.